# Retornar quantidade em bytes dos dados moveis utilizados por dia

Tags: android

Olá, estou com um problema em retornar a quantidade em bytes de dados consumidos via dados moveis no android.

atualmente estou utilizando este código:

```
Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        beginCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        beginCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);

        Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        endCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        endCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);

        UsageStatsManager lUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        final List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats= lUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, beginCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Mas meu queryUsageStats esta retornando 0. Neste caso estou tentando pegar o período de 1 ano.

Alguém saberia uma outra forma de retornar estes dados?

Agradeço desde já.